# How to format Friday, October 23rd 2015, 12:00:00 am to particular format datetime string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker have to get the datetime and add days to it

```
var get_date_time =  Friday, October 23rd 2015, 12:00:00 am
```

format get_date_time to oct 25 2015 12:00:00 am how to format

How to format this to

```
var d = new Date('oct 25 2015 12:00:00 am');
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2)
alert(d);
```

output should be
example

```
Tuesday, October 27th 2015, 12:00:00 am
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following...

Get your date `var d = new Date('Oct 25 2015 12:00:00 am')`.

Then use `d.getTime()` to get total time in milliseconds. Then for each day you wish to add, add 3600000 to it. Then create a new date from that `var newDate = new Date(1445758146777)`.

```
var d = new Date('Oct 25 2015 12:00:00 am');
var milisecs = d.getTime();
var oneDay = 3600000;
```

// Add one day to the date...

```
milisecs += oneDay;
var newDate = new Date(milisecs)
```

Then format it accordingly :-)

Comment: how to format Friday, October 23rd 2015, 12:00:00 am to Oct 25 2015 12:00:00 am

Comment: You can follow the info on the link @Reza provided to do the formatting no?

Answer (score 0):

I have used moment.js http: //momentjs.com/ to convert particular format

```
 var get_date_time =  Friday, October 23rd 2015, 12:00:00 am
```

using moment js i have formatted to date like the below

```
alert(moment(get_date_from,'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a').format("MMM DD YYYY h:mm:ss a"));
```

then i have followed like this to add number of days calculation

```
   var date1 = deal_from_date.setDate(deal_from_date.getDate() + 2);
```